# How to replace the lambda function with def function?

Tags: python

```
students2 = [
        {'name' : "harshit","score":90,'age':24},
        {'name' : "mohit","score":70,'age':19},
        {'name' : "rohit","score":60,'age':23}
]
print(max(students2, key = lambda i: i.get("score")))
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'harshit', 'score': 90, 'age': 24}
```

How can I replace the lambda function with `def` function?

Comment: Define a function and pass its pointer in that place

Comment: `def whatever(i): return i.get("score")`?

Comment: What does this have to do with `django`? Please tag only things that are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign some variable to a def. Something like:

```py
def get_score(students):
    return students.get("score")

print(max(students2), key=get_score)
```

This is a concept in functional programming called [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). Basically it means functions are treated in the same way as variables and can be passed to function, returned from functions, etc